# Design pattern for extract data text, check data format, out put data to console

Tags: c#, design-patterns, windows-console

I want To Know the best Design pattern for this problem:

I have text file continent data ie:

> ```
> ## "remove this line": 
> projectId  company  date  header3 header4 ..  
> 1    companyA   date1    data    data  
> 2    companyA   date2     data   data
> ```

my project is c# console application  :

I have to extract data from text file, remove extra line (ie start with "#"), check the data (ie: is date correct format? ),  order the data by (projectId, date) , to output the data in console

the input of the project is :
the user can set : 
- Link to the text file,
- an which order (order by data by projectId, or Date, ...)

N.B:
- Also the column in the text file can change position

My Questions: -what is the best design pattern for this problem?
              -do I need create Model for my data or just kept as dictionary string is better.

Comment: Always go with a model for something like this, IMO.  You have multiple columns, so you can read the text file and build a collection of the model instances (one per line), and use LINQ to Objects to sort/order.

Comment: Never heard of a design pattern for this… in my opinion, you should create a class to model the structure of a row because it makes ordering the collection a two-liner with Linq, the rest is mostly straightforward. If you insist, you can create an interface for the substeps to make sure you follow the right structure but I bet it doesn't gain you much in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about "design pattern", my take for this case is more or less like this below.

I will go with this approach if :

- the column name is dynamically defined by the text file
- need to sort by one of those columns

Here is the snippet :

```
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> TestDynamicModel(string SortBy)
    {
        var ret = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        //Get the column names first
        //These below just a sample
        var columnNames = new List<string>(); 
        columnNames.Add("projectid"); columnNames.Add("company"); columnNames.Add("date");

        //You may iterate through every row by the column names count. Something like "foreach(var column in columnNames) {};"
        //These below just a sample
        ret.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>()); ret[0].Add("projectid", "1"); ret[0].Add("company", "company B"); ret[0].Add("date", "1/2/2018");
        ret.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>()); ret[1].Add("projectid", "2"); ret[1].Add("company", "company A"); ret[1].Add("date", "1/2/2017");
        ret.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>()); ret[2].Add("projectid", "3"); ret[2].Add("company", "company C"); ret[2].Add("date", "1/2/2016");

        //Sort by your own customized IComparer
        ret.Sort(new DynamicSortBy(SortBy));

        return ret;
    }
```

And here is the IComparer class :

```
class DynamicSortBy : IComparer<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    string SortBy;

    public DynamicSortBy(string sortBy)
    {
        SortBy = sortBy;
    }

    public int Compare(Dictionary<string, string> x, Dictionary<string, string> y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x[SortBy], y[SortBy]);
    }
}
```

I'm not saying that this approach is better than using a model. Just in case you are looking for a more dynamic approach.

Just to give you an alternate solution.

Comment: Thank you for me answer , I solved the problem with approach using a model. but the company give it to me the project  didn't want to hire because the approach using a model for them is only wast of time ??? do you think is bad idea to use model ?????

Comment: Maybe they need to define their own models out-of-the-box, or maybe they want a feature to change the models in the future without changing the application itself. It's depend on the requirement, using model or not. That's why solving the problem the way you did, may still unacceptable from their point of view.